# jQuery replace on focusout

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I have been reading on this forum a lot of times but now I have a question of my own. I need to replace the string `01.01.2014` to `1. 1. 2014.` I have not been able to find a solution. This is the closest I have come.

```
$('#date').focusout(function () {
  var strText = $(this).val();
  strReplaceAll = strText.replace( new RegExp( "01", "g" ), "1. " );
  alert(strReplaceAll);
});
```

This will however return the string `1. 1. 21. 4`

I have tried with `.01` in tre RegExp string but this returns `1. 1. 21.`

So it seems that I cannot use "01.". So how can this be done? Hope someone can help me out with this problem.

Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regexp you show seems to be incorrect. Should it replace 02.02.2014, 15.03.2023 etc? If so, then you should use this replacement:

```
s.replace(/0(\d+)\./g, '$1. ')
```

Examples:

```
'01.01.2014'.replace(/0(\d+)\./g, '$1. ') // replaces to "1. 1. 2014"
'23.04.2029'.replace(/0(\d+)\./g, '$1. ') // replaces to "23.4. 2029"
'01.11.2029'.replace(/0(\d+)\./g, '$1. ') // replaces to "1. 11.2029"
```

Another solution (without regular expressions) behaving exactly like the previous one:

```
s = '01.01.2014'
s.split('.').map(parseFloat).join('. ') // replaces to "1. 1. 2014"
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can do it with:

```
var myregexp = /\b0(\d)\b/g;
result = subject.replace(myregexp, "$1");
```